# How do I use Bits type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, hugs

I am using WinHugs98 and I would like to do simple XOR of Int 10 with Int 11.

How do I do it?

**Current Attempt:**

```
Hugs> :l Data.Bits
Data.Bits> (Bits 10) `xor` (Bits 11)
ERROR - Undefined data constructor "Bits"
```

How do I convert the integer 10 and 11 to a "Bits" type so it can be used? Then I want to convert back to print on screen.

Edit for Louise Wasserman:

[image]

Comment: Since the Hugs project is no longer maintained since 2006, I would advise to use `ghci` instead.

Answer (score 3):

There is no conversion to be done.  `Int` is an *instance* of the `Bits` *class*, meaning the methods from `Bits` are defined for `Int`.  Just use `xor` directly:

```
10 `xor` 11
```

Comment: The following works: `(toInteger 10) \`xor\` (toInteger 11)`, nothing else does.

Comment: Try using `10 \`xor\` 11`.

Comment: Doesn't work on Hugs98. Look like `10` is not an `Int` or `Integer`.

Comment: Did you try with `xor` in backticks? With them, the type checker things you are trying to apply `10` to a value of type `a -> a -> a` and a value of type `b`.

Comment: @HermanSchoenfeld To be clearer: ``10 `xor` 11`` applies the `xor` function to the arguments `10` and `11` (using ```xor``` as an infix function). Whereas what your screenshot shows is `10 xor 11`, which is trying to apply the function `10` to the arguments `xor` and `11`; that isn't going to work (for reasons entirely unrelated to what you're trying to ask about, it was just a typo that's adding to your confusion).

Comment: It's a defaulting issue.  For GHC users, try making a file with ``main = print (10 `xor` 11)`` to see the problem, without GHCi's extended defaulting.  Essentially ``10 `xor` 11`` doesn't work because it doesn't know whether to pick `Int`, `Integer`, or something else.  ``10 `xor` 11 :: Integer`` should work.  In a real program the type signature will usually not be necessary, since there will be enough type information around to disambiguate.